# Makefile change -lpthread argument position?

Tags: c, makefile

I have a server that only compiles when I do `gcc server.c -o server -lpthread` but my makefile does it as `gcc -lpthread server.c -o server` and just hands me undefined reference errors. How can I change the `-lpthread` position?

Here's the file:

```
CC=gcc
CFLAGS=-lpthread

all: server
server: server.c

clean:
    rm -f server

run:
    server
    ./server
```

Comment: AFAIK, `-lpthread` should not be in `CFLAGS`, but in `LDFLAGS` or `LDLIBS`

Comment: i changed `CFLAGS` to `LDLIBS` and now it works. Post it as the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The list of libraries should go to `LDLIBS`, not `CFLAGS`. From the [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Implicit-Variables.html):

> LDLIBS
>
> Library flags or names given to compilers when they are supposed to invoke the linker, ‘ld’. LOADLIBES is a deprecated (but still supported) alternative to LDLIBS. Non-library linker flags, such as -L, should go in the LDFLAGS variable.

By using `LDLIBS`, the arguments should be at the correct position in the call to the compiler, after the input files.

Answer (score 1):

[You need to use `-pthread` command line option for both compiling and linking](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-7.3.0/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html#index-pthread). `-lpthread` is both insufficient and unnecessary:

```
CFLAGS := -pthread
LDFLAGS := -pthread
```